# Grails (2.3.11) persistence fields in MySQL have no default value

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails

We're using Grails 2.3.11 and MySQL 5.6.23

I've noticed that the columns for "id" and "version" don't have a default value specified.  Shouldn't Grails create both these columns with default values of null?

Comment: what is the point in having a default null value in a primary key field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ID and version fields (if your domain objects support versioning) should not be nullable.  Id fields are the primary keys and unique object identifiers in Grails... an object with no id value would be essentially un-retrievable by Grails/GORM.

The version field can be disabled via GORM configuration on the domain class, but if it exists it's needed for optimistic locking checks.

Comment: if the `version` is disabled, no field is generated for it.